# Automate docx and pptx editing using JavaScript

Tags: ms-office, office-js

Is it possible to automate editing Office document files with only using command line interface? I have licensed Office programs and want to write a script without using any third party solutions.

Also, is it possible to invoke office add-ins from outside Office applications using script?

I have searched for the solution and finally I am posting it here.

Comment: Have you looked at PHPExcel and PHPWord?

Comment: PHPOffice didn't came up while searching for the solution. PHPWord is just what I wanted. Also I found PHPPresentation fits for my solution. Thank you very much @Chris.

It would be awesome if the solution works with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right now you cannot automate office documents with our JS libraries, the way to do this is to use the Office Open XML SDK, who we recently open sourced. you can find info about this and how to use it here https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK